# How to create and import module properly in python

Tags: python, import, module

I'm trying to create python module that looks like this

```
/root
- main.py
    /my_module
     - foo.py
     - bar.py
```

And each .py files are below

main.py

```py
from my_module import bar

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    bar.hello()
```

foo.py

```py
def hi() :
    print("hi from foo")
```

bar.py

```py
import foo

def hello() :
    foo.hi()
    print("hello from bar")

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    hello()
```

You might noticed that when I run `main.py` it will fail with ImportError.
Because `import foo` is in `my_module` directory.
That is, at the aspect of `main.py`, `import foo` should be changed into `from my_module import foo`

However, When it was `from my_module import foo`, then `bar.py` will fail, because `foo.py` exists on same folder, not my_module

What I want is to make those all files(I mean, main.py and bar.py) works, leaving every `import` code as above , and in `elegant` way.

I don't think using `sys.path` is not cool, because there can be lots of nested folders in `my_module`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use `import my_module.foo` or `from . import foo`.

Comment: What do you mean by `bar.py` will fail? Are you executing `bar.py`? If so, how?

Comment: @9769953 yes, I'm going to execute `bar.py`, with shell command, (cd my_module, python3 bar.py)

Comment: the code I wrote gonna work with `python3 bar.py` but fails with `python3 main.py`. On the contrary, with `from my_module import foo` , `python3 main.py` works but `python3 bar.py` fails

Comment: You shouldn't execute a module like that. *If* (and that is quite a big if) you want to execute a module, use `python -m my_module.bar` instead. But generally, don't execute a module, unless you know what you're doing. Move the executable part outside of the package and turn it into a separate program that imports the module instead.

Comment: okay, i got it. thanks